# Bitcoin peer to peer network source code

Tags: development, peers, network

Does anybody know a place to get the source code of the Bitcoin Peer to Peer network? I only need the P2P network portion of the Bitcoin protocol. I am going to implement a new virtual currency. So i am going to reuse the existing bitcoin peer to peer network infrastructure for my project. Can someone advise me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for Bitcoin can be found at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin. The P2P part is integrated within the core Bitcoin code, and is not available separately.

Comment: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/net.cpp this part includes the network portion. But i don't know whether it is tightly coupled with other parts of the bitcoin source code. Could you able to advise me on how to separate P2P network portion from this?

Comment: If you are intending to create your own virtual currency, then you will already have the skills to do this. The networking part is not the hard part.

Comment: I'm only designing a new protocol. I need to reuse the existing Bitcoin P2P network source code. So i need to get an idea how it works. Could you able to provide me some explanations about this source code?